Is run loop synchronous or asynchronous?
I am doing some experiment based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17921058/767653
This is my minimum reproducible code:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  
  __block BOOL completed = NO;
  [self doMyWork:^{
    completed = YES;
  }];
  
  while (!completed) {
    [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
  }
}


My understanding is that, this code has a deadlock. Because the completion block is run on main thread, so in order for the completion block to run, viewDidLoad must return. And in order for viewDidLoad to return, completion block must be run to toggle the completed flag (hence circular wait).
However, when I run it, there's no deadlock in this code. Where I did understand wrongly?

You haven't blocked the main thread because at no time did you call a blocking wait.  RunUntilDate will prevent further execution within viewDidLoad but the main run loop is still processing.  You have certainly made the UI of your app non-responsive for three seconds. For a deadlock to occur you need three things - Mutual exclusion, no preemption and hold & wait - You don't have "hold & wait" in this case.

How is it possible to pause the execution of viewDidLoad while in the middle of it?  I thought you have to complete this function in order for main queue to pick up the next task. Or am i understanding it incorrectly? Also what did I do differently from the link I provided?

Replace [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]]; with Thread.sleep(1) and see what happens.  That is the difference between blocking the thread and delaying the return of viewDidLoad but still running the RunLoop.  Your current code has blocked UI updates and so is a bad idea, but the thread itself is not blocked because you have transferred execution back to the RunLoop.

I may have some trouble understanding "transferred the execution back to the run loop". Can the execution of a function be paused (and then execute another function) without switching thread? I am always under the impression that the execution of a function can be paused when switching thread (aka thread context switch), but didn't know that it's also possible within one thread. that's surprising.

if you call someOtherFunction() in viewDidLoad is execution paused?  No, you have transferred it to someOtherFunction.  In your case you have transferred it to runUntilDate and that function will continue to perform tasks in the run loop

There's only 1 call stack per thread. After calling someOtherFunction, the activation record (or "frame") of viewDidLoad is still in the call stack, and the new record for someOtherFrame simply sits on top of it. In my example, the only way this is possible is that runUntilDate actually calls my completion block. Am I understanding it correct?

Indirectly, yes. Your completion block is in the run loop timer queue.  Because you are keeping the RunLoop running it will eventually call your completion handler. As I said, use Thread.sleep instead and you will see a deadlock because you will have blocked the thread and prevented the RunLoop from running.

"There's only 1 call stack per thread"; that's also not exactly true. The dispatch model in iOS is much more complex than simple threads. You have grand central dispatch queues that are mapped to threads and runloops which manage the work that is dispatched.

No matter how fancy the GCD is, it's still built on top of threads tho. This means there can only be 1 call stack per thread. So in my example, if runUntilDate doesn't call my closure, then it would deadlock for sure.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You said:

My understanding is that, this code has a deadlock. Because the completion block is run on main thread, so in order for the completion block to run, viewDidLoad must return. And in order for viewDidLoad to return, completion block must be run to toggle the completed flag (hence circular wait).

Yes and no.
Technically, it is not a deadlock, as the run loop is still processing events. Your UI may appear to be responsive. But because viewDidLoad is not returning, some other events (like viewDidAppear) will not be called. There will be other consequences, too. This code interferes with the normal sequence of UI events, but is not technically a “deadlock”.
Bottom line, you must allow viewDidLoad (and all UIKit events) to promptly return. So, either dispatch this asynchronously (but avoid using the same serial queue for both the dispatch_async and the dispatch_after), or better, lose this spinning on the run loop, altogether.
Nowadays, spinning on the main run loop is almost always a mistake. GCD offers nice contemporary solutions. We would need more details regarding why you are spinning at all, though, to answer this broader question.

Your's [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runUntilDate... is doing main's runloop job, so deadlock doesn't occur.
It's secret technic of converting asynchronous functions to synchronous.
But you should use it only in emergency cases where converting code to asynchronous is not possible.
